# Select different type of inputs within cells in a .closest('tr')

Tags: javascript, input, html-table, closest

I have a `table` with a variable amount of rows like this:

```
<tr class"hotel-room">    
    <td class="cell1">
        <input type="hidden" class="hotel-id" name="input_01[label][row][progressive][id]" value="5893" />
        <input type="hidden" class="num-nights" name="input_01[label][row][progressive][nights]" value="2" />
        <select class="room-selection" name="input_01[label][row][progressive][]">
           <option value="etc"...>...options...</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="cell2">
        <input type="number" class="room-qty-input" name="input_01[label][row][progressive][]" />
    </td>
    <td class="cell3">
        <input type="text" class="room-price" name="input_01[label][row][progressive][]" />
    </td>
    <td class="buttons">
        stuff not relevant (two imgs, some text, more markup...)
    </td>
</tr>
```

While I'm inside `'room-qty-input'` number input field, I retrieve the parent `tr` of the container `td` using `var hotelRoom = $(this).closest('tr');`

while I'm a function where I passed the `'tr'` above, I need to get the following:

- the value of the second hidden field in the first cell with `class="num-nights"`
- the value of the number input field with `class="num-qty-input"`

These are supposed to be integers but they return as NaN. I tried to determine their value using:

- `var numbRooms = $(hotelRoom).find('input[type="number"]');`

or

- `var numbNights = $(hotelRoom).find('.num-nights').val();`

But they don't seem to return the correct value. This is within a bit messy function, perhaps I'm doing something else wrong. Would like to know if you have better methods for retrieving the data I'm looking for.

Comment: You're missing the closing `"` on all the `name` attributes, which might be making the `value` be not parsed correctly.

Comment: sorry guys the typo is not in the actual code; just in the transcription here; the actual code is a bit longer but I trimmed it for clarity - in the process I missed that quote; it's not fixing the issue, but thanks for pointing out anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging what you said you did into [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ogodug/1/), I can't see anything wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.room-qty-input")
        .on('focus', function () {
            var hotelRoom = $(this).closest('tr');
            var numbNights = hotelRoom.find('.num-nights').val();
            if (isNaN(numbNights)) console.log('NaN'); else console.log('is number');
            console.log(this, hotelRoom, numbNights);
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry I actually didn't copypaste my actual code because that's rather longer; while transcribing it, I must have missed out that quotation mark - thanks for pointing out though I still haven't solved my main problem

Comment: @Fulvio check my code...I can't see anything wrong with the method you used, but you didn't post your actual JavaScript code so I wrote code based on what you said you did.

Comment: thanks saluce - actually my calculations were wrong because I was I was omitting .val at the end of numbRooms = $(hotelRoom).find('input[type="number"]'); I was looking for numbRooms.val in another var but that didn't work and messed up the calculations as one of the values returned NaN. I was worried that closest('tr') wasn't a safe method, but it turns out it is good enough. Thanks again